# Are JSON and Node.js Querystring the same?

Tags: json, node.js

On node.js, are JSON methods (parse, stringify) the same as Query Sting methods (parse, stringify) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Let's try:

```
var qs  = require('querystring');
var obj = { 'foo' : '1 + 2' };

console.log(qs.stringify(obj));
// result: foo=1%20%2B%202

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
// result: {"foo":"1 + 2"}
```

So, no, they aren't :-)

Comment: @robertklep When it comes to speed, would qs stringify be faster than JSON.stringify? I read somewhere JSON.stringify is slow. Thanks.

Comment: @Woppi I ran [a benchmark](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/36decb99c0fe63ce00987314119c1c88) to check: `qs.stringify` is really slow, `JSON.stringify` is reasonably fast, and `querystring.stringify` (Node built-in) is an absolute winner (although it doesn't support "extended" querystring parameters, so it will only work with simple objects).

Comment: @robertklep thank you so much, I didn't know Node has built in querystring before your answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Talking names. The query string methods return strings suitable for use in a URL query string. I. e., they are percent-escaped. That's not at all related to JSON.